# What is inside in $item in start_el function in Walker_Nav_Menu class

Tags: menus, navigation, walker

I want to know what are exactly inside the $item in start_el function in Walker Class. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the source of the class-walker-nav-menu.php, [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/#source).
There you can find the `start_el` method and in the commends just before the method saying that the `$item` variable is `@param WP_Post  $item   Menu item data object.`. So, it's a post with post type `nav_menu_item`. You can have a look to the `wp_setup_nav_menu_item` function ([here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_setup_nav_menu_item/)) which builds up a menu item.

The above is the background. To actually see the contents of an item, you can call
a filter in the `start_el` method and print the `$item` variable,
e.g.:

```
function what_the_item( $args, $item, $depth ) {

    // pretty print the contents of $item
    highlight_string("<?php\n\$item =\n" . var_export($item, true) . ";\n");

    // Because this filter will be called way more than one time,
    // in order to make the output cleaner, you can stop php execution
    // right after the print of the $item so only one $item will be displayed!
    // die();
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_item_args', 'what_the_item', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Thanks I will review it.